# Specify Oracle Schema for SQLAlchemy Engine

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, schema

I need to create a SQLAlchemy engine for a database, that doesn't use the default schema. What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

string = "oracle+cx_oracle://batman:batpassword@batcave.com:1525/some_database"
engine = create_engine(string, schema="WEIRD_SCHEMA")
tables = engine.table_names()
```

Is there a way to do this?

I'm working with some legacy code, that uses [`engine.table_names()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.table_names) method.

Comment: Pass the `schema` argument to [`table_names()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.table_names)? From the docs: "schema – Optional, retrieve names from a non-default schema."

Comment: Unfortunately the actual `table_names()` call is deep inside some legacy code, so it's not quite that easy. For now I've subclassed the object, and am providing the schema in that class, but it would be nice if you could specify the schema for the engine.

Comment: In that case I think you possibly could listen to [Pool checkout event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.checkout) and set the [`current_schema`](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.current_schema) attribute of the cx_oracle connection. Not sure if that actually works, but worth a try, I guess.

Comment: Alternatively you could use [PoolEvents.connect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.connect).

Comment: I'll check it out.